# Set up a build step executed only when the project is built from Visual Studio but not on the build server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, msbuild-task

How can I set a build step that is executed only when built from Visual Studio and not on the build server?

I want a build step for local debugging, but I do not want this step to run when my build runs on TeamCity.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute your logic conditionally on the presence of an [environment variable](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Predefined+Build+Parameters)

Since your question is tagged MSBuild you can do this

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build">    
    <Target Name="Build" Condition="'$(TEAMCITY_VERSION)' == ''">  
        <Message Text="Building..."/>  
    </Target>  
</Project>
```